# Can Snowflake COPY INTO from CSV without any interpretation date or time columns?

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to load Snowflake tables with all columns defined as varchar2 using COPY INTO, but Snowflake keeps trying to interpret the file fields as a date or time. Is there an option to say something like DATE_FORMAT=NOAUTO? Because of the variability of these files, the number of date/datetime columns, and their formats, we handle the conversion of the formats via another process.

Will, using the COPY INTO ... FROM SELECT () prevent the field interpretations?

Comment: If you don't want to interpret the dates, make your target table DDL into VARCHAR, instead of DATE.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type cast your field values from stage you can use simple SQL statement to do so.

select to_char($1),to_char($2) from @stage1/sample1.csv.gz;

Also you can insert directly to your target table.

insert into TEST111 select to_char($1),to_char(2) from @stage1/sample1.csv.gz;

There are so many option to format the record from your stage to target, refer the below link
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: Ironically, I do NOT want any typecasting. That's the problem. Of all the options in the referenced doc, there's no option to say "do not interpret". But your answer speaks very closely to the simplest answer.

Comment: If possible share one or two records

Answer (score 0):

Yes, COPY INTO ... FROM SELECT () prevents the field interpretations.

```
copy into MY_TABLE
from (select t.$1, t.$2, t.$3, ...
      from @snamed_stage t);
```

... for the data in the stage, the 2nd field had data formatted like mm/dd/yyyy. It was NOT interpreted and the table column 2 has the text values. The 3rd field had data with a yyyy/mm/dd format and the table column 3 has the text values.